# I'm unable to install my locally written Python packages onto a new Windows 11 laptop

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I'm unable to install my own existing packages to a fresh installation of Python 3.11 on a new Windows laptop. I successfully transferred several of the packages to new PCs in 2019 using `setup.py`, which I believe is deprecated, so I have been trying for several days to use `setup.cfg`/`pyproject.toml`, without success.
The test module `crhGV.py` has worked without problems on several PCs since 2016. It can be run without errors from the command line.
*pip* suggests that the installation was successful:

```
D:\dataNikau\progLan\python3\crhLib\gv>python -m pip list
Package         Version
--------------- -------
build           0.10.0
colorama        0.4.6
**crhGV           2.0**
packaging       23.1
pip             23.0.1
pyproject_hooks 1.0.0
setuptools      65.5.0
```

I'm using an administrator user for all of this work.

- `python -m build`
- `python -m pip install .\dist\crhGV-2.0.tar.gz`

This results in the `C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\crhGV-2.0.dist-info` folder being created but I think there should also be a `crhGV` folder containing the `crhGV.py` script.
I am not receiving any error messages and a Windows search command does not find any copies of a `crhGV.py` file on the `C:` drive.
Trying to import `crhGV` in a test Python script fails (`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crhGV'`).
I have tried adding the required `crhGV` folder manually to site-packages. This allows the Python import command to complete without error but the module is still not usable.
During the troubleshooting I have cleanly installed Python 3.11.2 twice and Python 3.11.3 once and made several attempts to install the module. On the 1st attempt I installed several modules and packages but restricted the install process to one module on the subsequent attempts.
I don't know why the installation is failing and I have run out troubleshooting ideas. Any suggestions on how to proceed would be appreciated.

`setup.cfg` and `pyproject.toml` files...

---

```
#! python3
# crhGV setup.cfg
# v1.0.2 crh 09-apr-23 -- replaces setup.py

[metadata]
name = crhGV
version = 2.0
description = crh tier 1 module: shared global variables
keywords  =  tier1
author = **
author_email = **
url = ciscrh/python3/crhLib/gv

[options]
package_dir=
    =src
packages = find:
python_requires = >=3.11

[options.packages.find]
where=src
```

---

```
#! python3
# pyproject.toml
# v1.00 crh 09-apr-23 -- minimal pyproject.toml configuration

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

-------- several days later...

My approach of using pyproject.toml and setup.cfg files wasn't working and wasn't generating errors, making it very difficult to troubleshoot. I eventually changed to just using a pyproject.toml file. I found getting the correct format quite challenging because there are a lot of examples available that didn't work for me. I think the pyproject.toml method is still evolving so much of what I tried was based on examples with syntax that doesn't work now. Eventually I got a working configuration file for a single source module, and with some more experimentation I managed to get my packages with multiple modules working as well. So now I've abandoned setup.py and setup.cfg in favour of a single pyproject.toml file, which might have a few more lines than necessary.
Before the breakthrough I had updated the pip utility to version 23.1, only released a few days ago. I have no reason to believe that this point update for pip made any difference to the solution.

```
#! python3
# pyproject.toml for crhDateUtil
# v1.00 crh 20-apr-23 -- pyproject.toml configuration

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=65"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "crhDateUtil"
version  = "2.0"
description = "crh tier 2 module: date utilities"
authors = [{name = "CRH", email = "***"}]
readme = {file = "README.txt", content-type = "text/markdown"}
requires-python = ">=3.11"
keywords = ["tier 2", "date utilities", "crhDate", "crhParseDate"]

[options]
package_dir = "src"
 
[options.packages.find]
where = "src"
```

Comment: Without seeing any code or configuration files, it is hard to help. -- Also keep in mind that StackOverflow is not meant as support for people's own personal issues, but to build a general Q&A repository that can be useful to anyone. As it is now, your question is not really a question and can not really be given an answer in a format suitable for StackOverflow.

Comment: OK, I'll provide the setup.cfg  and pyproject.toml files once I work out how to get the markdown code to work.

Comment: Yes, the best is to provide a so-called [mre].

Comment: I've now added a minimal reproducible example into the main text of the body description

Comment: What is the project's directory structure? Are there a `crhTest/__init__.py` and a `chrGV/__init__.py` files? Such files can be completely empty but they have to be there.

Comment: Not sure at all about that, but what comes to my mind is that your pip install does not reference the correct python interpreter. (Again, I am not sure at all, just a thought)

Comment: Yes, as @Itération122442 said, it can be that some of your commands are not running with the Python interpreter you think is running. Try to be more explicit: `python3.11 -m pip list`, `python3.11 -m build`, `python3.11 -m pip install ...`, `python3.11 test03.py` and so on.

Comment: During the initial testing all my files were in the same folder for crhGV, but I later added the src subfolder & moved the crhGV.py & __init__.py files into it. That is a structure I saw during my investigations, which made sense to me. It hasn't modified the outcome AFAICS. The crhTest module was set up with the same subfolder structure from the outset.

Comment: I initially used simple build & pip install commands, but as a result of my investigations I changed to using the python -m prefix format because I understood that it would force the use of the correct version of the tools. I will repeat the process using a more specific prefix to see if that makes any difference.
The package installation was carried out on a clean first-time installation of Python 3.11.2, & the first remove/reinstall Python process was done to see if that helped. The remove/install Python 3.11.3 was done to see if the point upgrade made any difference; it didn't :-(

Comment: I've done a lot more checking here. I've only got one version of Python installed (Python 3.11.3). I uninstalled the existing version (Python 3.11.2)  using the Windows Add/remove Programs option & then manually deleted the few remaining folders & files in C:Program Files\Python311 before restarting the PC & installing Python 3.11.3 the other day.
All the variants of python, pip & build I've looked into either don't work or use the same versions of pip & build. I conclude that I might as well carry on using the python -m pip & python -m build commands used so far. See main entry for details.

Comment: I still do not see the project directory structure, which is very important to me to be able to help you. I recommend [this tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/), pay close attention to the directory structure. In your case it seems like you need `src/chrGV/__init__.py` -- From my point of view this question now has too many irrelevant details. I recommend you focus your question on a single [mre]. -- Also it seems like your question is about asking for individual support for you own personal case, instead of being a Q&A in the spirit of StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you for your help. To clarify a couple of points, there is a lot of detail but all of it was added in response to requests for more information, mostly from you. And I did give you the directory structure - I stated that I added the subfolder src & moved the crhGV.py and __init__.py files into it. So the structure is gv/src, with the setup.cg and pyproject.txt files remaining in the original gv folder. Note that I originally had all of these files in the gv folder.

Comment: Seems to me like your project's directory structure is incorrect. So *setuptools* is not able to find the importable packages, sub-packages, and modules. The project directory structure should be such that you have a file `src/chrGV/__init__.py`. Check the directory structure in this [tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/). -- I do not know how to do it on Windows, on Linux there is the utility called [`tree`](https://linuxhandbook.com/tree-command/) to output the directory structure. This kind of output would be valuable in your question.

Comment: Package installation now working using just the pyproject.toml file, an example of which is given in the above text.

Comment: The `[options]` and `[options.packages.find]` do nothing in a `pyproject.toml`, I am quite confident you can remove them. *setuptools* by default is able to automatically detect the `src` layout, so you should not need these 2 sections.